# "Open With" menu for remote files

Tags: cocoa, macos, launching-application

I'm getting troubles getting the applications associated with a remote file how has a URL like: "http://servername/folder/file.png".

The code I use is:

```
...
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://servername/folder/file.png"];
NSArray *apps = (NSArray *)LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL((CFURLRef) url,kLSRolesAll);
...
```

I also try using `URLWithString:` but the result is the same.
What is the correct approach for this?

**Edit after Joshua replay:**

Sorry for may bad redaction. The problem is that the `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` call return nil.

Answer (score 0):

First, `-fileURLWithPath:` expects a file system path like `@"/Users/me/Desktop/MyFile.png"`.

Second, you don't say what the "same" results are and what is wrong with them, so it's difficult to tell you what the problem is.

The docs say this:

> If the item URL’s scheme is file
>   (designating either a file or a
>   directory), the selection of suitable
>   applications is based on the
>   designated item’s filename extension,
>   file type, and creator signature,
>   along with the role specified by the
>   inRolesMask parameter; otherwise, it
>   is based on the URL scheme (such as
>   http, ftp, or mailto).

So what are you getting and what do you expect to get?